# Pass a variable from one html page to another html page

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I am using Google Apps Script to make a webapp. Can't find any way to pass a value from one HTML page to another HTML page..but I can't find a way to do that. Any opinions will be appreciated

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]